# Initializing a xib on a UIViewController's subview

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, scrollview, xib

I'm using [DZNEmptySet](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet) to load when there's nothing to display in a UITableView. It works fine for DZNEmptySet's methods like `titleForEmptyDataSet`, `imageForEmptyDataSet`, but not the one I want to use (which is `customViewForEmptyDataSet`).

When I try to load the xib into the `scrollView.frame`, Xcode's memory starts bloating in 30 megabyte increments and the app hangs. I know I'm at fault, but I don't know what I'm mucking up.

I've looked at many answers here and tutorials on other sites, but I can't find a solution that works for this circumstance (which I think is pretty simple). Any feedback on that front would be greatly appreciated.

Here's `customViewForEmptyDataSet` on `MyViewController`

```
// App hangs on this and memory bloats in 30 megabyte increments.
func customViewForEmptyDataSet(scrollView: UIScrollView!) -> UIView! {
    return EmptySetView(frame: scrollView.frame)
}
```

Here's the class for my `EmptySetView` that I'm trying to initialize:

```
import UIKit

class EmptySetView: UIView {
    var view: UIView!
    // These are connected to a xib
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewTextView: UITextView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass:self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "EmptySetView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }
}
```

**Update**

At [Matt's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38511909/4475605), I investigated recursion I was experiencing and discovered source of the problem.

You do not specify the UIView class on the **View** for your xib. Instead, you click the yellow cube titled **File's Owner** and specify the `UIView` there, leaving the class field empty on the **View** in the Document Outline panel.

[image]

After cleaning caches and rebuilding, I can get the view to load in the hierarchy with this code called on `MyViewController`:

```
func customViewForEmptyDataSet(scrollView: UIScrollView!) -> UIView! {
    let emptySetView = EmptySetView(frame: scrollView.frame)
    return emptySetView
}
```

The `EmptySetView` xib and `MyViewController` don't know about each other until the xib is loaded, so you'll need to deal with layout constraints.

Comment: from where do you call 'customViewForEmptyDataSet'

Comment: Use Instruments. It will show you immediately what the source of the problem is. You can watch the memory grow and view the call chain that causes it.

Comment: @NickCatib `customViewForEmptyDataSet` is a delegate method that gets called if the `tableView` is empty.

Comment: @matt I put it in Instruments for Leaks and I think my problem lives in `    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }`. I think the `setup()` call is causing the issue. Every example I've looked at has the init frame & init coder w/ looking virtually the same. I'll keep plugging away resting assured that I'm doing something startlingly silly.

Comment: I'm sure you are infinitely recursing but I am too tired to tell you where. The debugger will show you instantly.

Comment: Okay, perhaps I've guessed it (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that in the nib you are loading the top level view is itself an EmptySetView. This is causing a recursion. You start by instantiating the EmptySetView in code:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}
```

In `setup()`, you load the nib. But this causes an EmptySetView to be instantiated *again*, from the nib. This time, the other initializer is called:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}
```

But `setup()` loads the nib, so we are now going around in circles, trying to nest an infinite number of nib-loaded views inside one another like matrushka dolls.

Comment: Thank you! I made some progress getting the recursion issue resolved. The view now loads, but the auto layout constraints specified on the xib don't seem to be respected when it loads. I updated my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't feel to me like an update: it's a whole different question. It appears that my answer was right; I feel you should accept it. If you then have a new issue, ask it as a different question and I'll be glad to help if I can. Otherwise you're just leeching - turning your question into a moving target from which no one can ever earn the "accepted" checkmark, and asking for more and more help "for free".

Comment: Mind if I edit your answer to add one should check that the File Owner specifies the UIView class, not the View in the xib? That's what was causing the recursion.

Comment: What was causing the recursion was what I said caused it: you had set the top level view's class to EmptySetView. This has nothing to do with the File's Owner. The File's Owner can be anything at all. It should be the class of whoever will be owner at nib-loading time, but that has nothing to do with the problem you were having. (Of course, if the File's Owner is _not_ the right class, you'll have a different problem, because your outlets won't work; but that's not what the question was about.)

Comment: By the way, you might want to read my book to understand the nib-loading process: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_nib_loading_and_file_8217_s_owner You seem to be thrashing around a bit because of nibs and nib-loading.

Comment: That is AWESOME! I haven't worked with them much, but I'm beginning to see where they're useful. I just glanced through it and it seems like it will clarify a lot. Thank you for sharing.